# Generate aAMAccountName from CSV with PowerShell (Substring)

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a question you might help me with my query, I did a script that imports all users from Excel files.

The question is how can I generate sAMAccountName which starts a specific string, for example, the user name is Joris Ahamd.
I want Joris sAMAccountName should be like that GOTJAH
the first letter of Joris name J and the first two letters of last name AH and "GOT" to be as default with all users.

I hope that was clear enough otherwise I will try to explain mote .

Here is the script

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  
#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Script\Poweshell\samer1.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
#Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    
$Username   = $User.username
$Password   = $User.password
$Firstname  = $User.firstname
$Lastname   = $User.lastname
$OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
$email      = $User.email
$streetaddress = $User.streetaddress
$city       = $User.city
$zipcode    = $User.zipcode
$state      = $User.state
$country    = $User.country
$telephone  = $User.telephone
$jobtitle   = $User.jobtitle
$company    = $User.company
$department = $User.department
$Password = $User.Password


#Check to see if the user already exists in AD
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
{
     #If user does exist, give a warning
     Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
}
else
{
    #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
    
    #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $username `
        -UserPrincipalName "$Username@consiliumsafety.com" `
        -Name "$Lastname,$Firstname" `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
        -Path "OU=Malmo,DC=consilium,DC=net"`
        -City $city `
        -Company $company `
        -State $state `
        -StreetAddress $streetaddress `
        -OfficePhone $telephone `
        -EmailAddress $email `
        -Title $jobtitle `
        -Department $department `
        -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Khaled, were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not say which shell you are using, but assuming bash:

PREPEND='GOT'

SamAccountName="$PREPEND${Firstname:0:1}${Lastname:0:2}"

Answer (score 0):

Since your script is written in PowerShell I will assume you want the solution using that language. You should use the [Substring() method](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html) to extract the parts of the name you need.

Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
PS C:\> $Firstname = "Joris"
PS C:\> $Lastname = "Ahamd"
PS C:\> $Firstname.Substring(0,1)
J
PS C:\> $Lastname.Substring(0,2)
Ah
PS C:\> $Username = ("GOT"+$($Firstname.Substring(0,1))+$($Lastname.Substring(0,2))).ToUpper()
PS C:\> $Username
GOTJAH
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped me but the only thing which I'm trying to fix now how to change the email address cause the email looks like GOTJAH@domain.com.

Comment: Change it from what exactly? If you could edit the original question, I'll update my answer.